# Deleting consecutive empty strings in an array, but one

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to write a function that replaces all the vowels (a,e,i,o,u) in a string and keeps one separator ('') between consonants. For example:

```js
Input: 'kkkeoiekkk'
Output: ['kkk', '', 'kkk']
```

My try:

```js
function split(para) {

    let regex = /[a|e|i|o|u]/g;
    let arr = para.replace(regex, '-').split('-');

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === '' && arr[i - 1] === '') {}
    }
    return arr
}
```

Right now for the input split('hheeooook') I get back [ 'h', '', '', '', 'k' ] instead of ['h', '', 'k']. Thanks for everyone reading or pointing out what is wrong with my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slight variation on your attempt. It is mainly the regex which needed change.

```js
  function split (para) {
  let regex = /[aeiou]+/g;
  let arr = para.replace(regex, '  ').trim().split(' ');
  return arr
}
console.log(split('kkhkeoiektr'));
console.log(split('akkeoihhkoo'));
console.log(split('kkeoihhkoo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without regex:

```js
function split(para) {
    let res = [];
    let tmp = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
        if ('aeiou'.includes(para[i])) {
            if (tmp.length) {
                res.push(tmp);
                res.push('');
                tmp = '';
            }
        } else {
            tmp += para[i];
        }
    }

    if (tmp.length) {
        res.push(tmp);
    } else {
        if (res.length > 0)
            res.pop();
    }

    return res;
}

console.log(split('kkkeoiekkk'));
console.log(split('kkkeoiekkka'));
console.log(split('kkkeoiekkkak'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate to split the string.

```
var dict = {"a":1,"e":1,"i":1,"o":1,"u":1};
const src = 'kkkeoiekkk0qwert';
var pre = "";
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < src.length; i++){
    var char = src.charAt(i);
    console.log(char);
    console.log(pre);
    if(dict[char]){
        if(pre){
            result.push(pre);
            pre = "";
        }
    }else{
        pre += char;
    }
}
if(pre){
    result.push(pre);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `reg.exec`:

```js
function split (para) {
  let res = [""], reg = /[^aeiou]+/g, match;
  while(match = reg.exec(para)) res.push(match[0], "");
  return res.slice(1, res.length - 1);
}

console.log(split('kkhkeoiektr'));
console.log(split('akkeoihhkoo'));
console.log(split('kkeoihhkoo'));
console.log(split('kkkk'));
console.log(split('aeiou'));
```